# Smooth transition from php to asp.net c#

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, transition

I was wondering if anyone has any tips on transitioning from PHP to asp.net c#? I've been developing in PHP for 7 years and I'm interested in learning asp.net. However, I've been disappointed with the books that I've read so far. Seems like every asp.net book has so many examples of clicking here and dragging here and right click on this, etc... that I seem to get lost. Learning the C# language isn't bad...I think I'm getting lost in either the IDE or the .NET framework. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, it's mostly about using the MSVS GUI (and much less about learning ASP.Net syntax) (or, heaven forbid, learning exactly what all that auto-generated code is actually *doing*).

Comment: If you're interested in the "how stuff works" aspect, or subtleties about how to use the .Net languages effectively, I highly recommend Andrew Troelsen's "Pro C#":  http://www.amazon.com/dp/1430225491/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suggest you look at asp.net/mvc, not webforms - it will be a more natural migration.

The good resource is the official site: http://asp.net/mvc - it has tutorials, videos and more.

The .NET base class library (BCL) is *very* large. It is what you will interact with most of the time (outside of your own code). The only advice I can give - look things up on MSDN. It has very good documentation and it is worth taking your time reading through it.

For Visual Studio - the [VS tips and tricks blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/) is a really good resource to learn about it.

Comment: Thanks for the great info. I'm actually looking into mvc right now...I'm not sure why I didnt start there since I use that design pattern when coding php. Oh well, live and learn :)

Answer (score 3):

Coming from PHP there's probably less you need to un-learn (I was a classic ASP programmer for a long time and made the jump to .NET about seven years ago).

Microsoft has a bunch of free tutorials, as does the W3Schools site. I found the Macon State tutorials to be extremely helpful when I was starting out:

http://www.maconstateit.net/tutorials/aspnet20/default.htm

The Microsoft exam prep books are pretty straightforward, too, mostly dealing with code instead of drag-and-drop.

Comment: Please don't recommend w3schools - see here: http://w3fools.com

Comment: w3schools isn't perfect, but it's still a great resource.  Its critics (notably Paul Irish) strike me as self-important fascists.  Knowledgeable, but still way too self-righteous, arrogant and full of themselves.  Kind of "talk radio for the hacker crowd" ;)

Answer (score 0):

I felt the exact same way about the .NET / Visual Studio environment when I first approached it.

If you're not into all the GUI stuff I would recommend George Shepherd's ASP.NET 4 Step by Step from Microsoft Press.

I learned ASP.NET basics on the 3.5 version of this book and I loved it.  He really starts with the nuts and bolts stuff (open a telnet window and interact directly with the HTTP server for example) that I think would appeal to most *NIX veterans.  His approach gave me a good feel for what all the complicated controls in ASP.NET are really doing under the hood, which was instrumental in growing my understanding of the platform.

[http://www.amazon.com/Microsoft-ASP-NET-Step/dp/0735627010/ref=sr_1_5?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1325190956&sr=1-5](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735627010)